# Date column won't convert if I use it in the where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have this code that runs great:

```
SELECT 
  QuoteDet.QuoteNo, 
  Quote.SalesID, 
  Quote.CustCode, 
  QuoteDet.PartNo AS [Version], 
  QuoteDet.Price1 AS [Unit Price], 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(QuoteDet.User_Text1 AS DATE), 1) AS [Submittal Date]  
FROM QuoteDet INNER JOIN Quote ON QuoteDet.QuoteNo = Quote.QuoteNo
WHERE QuoteDet.Status IN ('Req', 'Pend')
AND QuoteDet.User_Text1 <> 'HOLD'
GROUP BY QuoteDet.QuoteNo, Quote.SalesID, Quote.CustCode, QuoteDet.PartNo, 
QuoteDet.Price1, QuoteDet.User_Text1
ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(QuoteDet.User_Text1 AS DATE), 1)
```

But when I add the following condition in the where clause to get the current week, I get the message "Conversion failed when converting date and or time from character string

```
SELECT 
  QuoteDet.QuoteNo, 
  Quote.SalesID, 
  Quote.CustCode, 
  QuoteDet.PartNo AS [Version], 
  QuoteDet.Price1 AS [Unit Price], 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(QuoteDet.User_Text1 AS DATE), 1) AS [Submittal Date]  
FROM QuoteDet INNER JOIN Quote ON QuoteDet.QuoteNo = Quote.QuoteNo
WHERE QuoteDet.Status IN ('Req', 'Pend') 
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(QuoteDet.User_Text1 AS DATE), 1) >= 
DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(QuoteDet.User_Text1 AS DATE), 1) <  
DATEADD(DAY, 8-DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
AND QuoteDet.User_Text1 <> 'HOLD'
GROUP BY QuoteDet.QuoteNo, Quote.SalesID, Quote.CustCode, QuoteDet.PartNo, 
QuoteDet.Price1, QuoteDet.User_Text1
ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(QuoteDet.User_Text1 AS DATE), 1)
```

Why don't I get the error in the first query?  It's also converting to a date, yet no error

Comment: Tip: `GetDate()` is treated a bit oddly in queries. Each _instance_ will have a constant value within a query. For example `select GetDate() as D1, GetDate() as D2 from SomeTable` may return two different values for the two columns, but they will not vary from one row to the next. When using `GetDate()` in multiple statements, e.g. within a stored procedure, one may avoid interesting surprises by getting a single value and using it throughout, i.e. `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();` and use `@Now` as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility, first query works, because the conversion in the select clause happens after the narrowing of rows by the where clause. By moving the convert to the where clause it can now be run on all rows, some of which may have bad data that does not make it through to the select clause in the first query.

If you are on a sufficiently new version of SQL Server, [TRY_PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql) will allow conversions without errors by returning NULL for un-convertable strings.

Comment: That TRY_PARSE works amazing, thanks.  Still no idea why my original code failed.  I tried every combination of CONVERT(CAST()) and just CAST().  Neither worked, but TRY_PARSE works like a charm

Comment: @CristianContreras This might be an error due to anonymising production code. In the second query you have `QuoteDet.User_Text1 <> 'HOLD'` and `CAST(QuoteDet.User_Text1 AS DATE)`. Any row where `QuoteDet.User_Text1` is _HOLD_ is going to fail the cast to a date.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure the hold is the issue, just wasn't sure why the first query was able to convert with no issue.  I suppose it has something to do with the order in which the query executes

Answer (score 1):

In your first query you are:

- first casting the 'QuoteDet.User_Text1' as a Date
- then converting the result to a VARCHAR of length 30, resulting in a string

In your second query, you are trying to use a string to check for a date. What you should do in the WHERE clause is to remove the 'Convert' method call, and just use the 'Cast' method. So instead of this:

```
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(QuoteDet.User_Text1 AS DATE), 1)
```

you have to use the following in your WHERE clause:

```
    CAST(QuoteDet.User_Text1 AS DATE)
```

Comment: But then my first query wouldn't work either, yet that one is able to convert without error.  I have tried just using the CAST only.  Same problem, first query works, second one doesn't.  Not sure why having that column in the WHERE clause makes the code crash

Comment: @CristianContreras, There is an additional convert, implied, from the varchar back to the date to do the comparison in the where clause. That is not happening in the select clause.

Comment: In the first query, you are using the  CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(QuoteDet.User_Text1 AS DATE), 1)  to show a value. In the where clause you need to compare the value with other dates. That's why it's working in the first query.